# How to get SD-card write access on Honor 6x with Android 7.0?

Tags: rooting, external-sd, 7.0-nougat, huawei-honor-6

My phone is a Huawei Honor 6x, using Android 7.0 (Nougat). EMUI version 5.04.

I want my music apps to have write access to my music folders on my external micro SD-card. I understand that this might only be possible if **all** my apps have access to **all** my folders on the card.

I would prefer to do this without rooting my phone, but if that is not possible, then please recommend alternate methods.

**What I've already done**:

Install *Fx File Explorer* on my phone, but this only creates write permissions for itself, not for other apps. That seems plausible of course, but that was not as I was told.

Questions:

1. How do I get write access to folders on my external micro SD-card, without rooting?
2. If it is not possible to get access without rooting, what is the best method to root for my type of phone and OS?
3. Can I root my  my type of phone and OS **without** or **with** unlocking the bootloader?
4. Is formatting the SD card as internal storage a better option? Or do I need to root my phone to do that anyway?

Comment: Can you create or delete files/folders using Fx File Explorer on the sd-card? You know that every app has to request write permission on the sd-card on it's own. This process is very cryptic and usually not well explained as it opens the built-in file explorer and you have to perform certain actions: https://metactrl.com/docs/sdcard-on-lollipop/

Comment: yes i can do that